# Docker-compose rails image won't start after reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, dockerfile

It ran just before I rebooted my machine, and suddenly I get `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory` when starting the container.

During build, which completes without issue, I can see the contents of /app are correct, but on startup, /app only contains a .bundle directory and nothing else.

*UPDATE*: Turns out the volume `./documents_api:/app` is what isn't working. Environment is docker for windows 17.09.1 running as administrator

Here is my folder structure:

```
./
  .env
  docker-compose.yml
  documents_api/
    <typical rails directory contents>
    Dockerfile
```

.env just contains `RAILS_ENV=development`

the dockerfile contains:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /app
```

docker-compose.yml contains:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - mongo:/var/lib/mongo
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  documents:
    build: ./documents_api
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./documents_api:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - "3000"
    depends_on:
      - database

  frontend:
    image: nginx
    build: ./web
    depends_on:
      - documents
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "144:144"

# Persistence
volumes:
  mongo:
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to remap my shared drives in the settings. It had lost the credentials after the reboot and was silently failing to map the volume.